# Unicorn web server won't start after changing ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I'm created a new droplet in digitalocean with ubuntu 12.04 and rails 4.0.2, the thing is that we needed to downgrade rails to 3.2, which i did.  But when I try to start unicorn I get the following:

*** Starting Unicorn web server unicorn                                          start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn (No such file or directory)**

I have Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3-p484.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem, I need to edit the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH in /etc/init.d/unicorn, after this it works.

Comment: Please check your unicorn.error.log file to know an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via comment from asker:

"Edit the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH in /etc/init.d/unicorn, after this it works."